# Why do I get the same logger in multiple processes

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I got duplicate log when logging into a single file from different process.
Why do I get the same logger in multiple processes? And the logger has some Handler.

**My Code:**

```
def get_queue_logger(q):
    qh = QueueHandler(q)
    root = logging.getLogger()
    print(f"Logger: {id(root)}, Handlers: {root.handlers}")
    root.addHandler(qh)
    return root


def main():
    q = Manager().Queue()

    pool = Pool()
    for i in range(10):
        pool.apply(
            func=get_queue_logger,
            args=(q,)
        )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Console:**

```
Logger: 2041926265200, Handlers: []
Logger: 2095359404400, Handlers: []
Logger: 1781876664688, Handlers: []
Logger: 3222115264880, Handlers: []
Logger: 2041926265200, Handlers: [<QueueHandler (NOTSET)>]  # The same logger
Logger: 1705732548976, Handlers: []
Logger: 2505966954864, Handlers: []
Logger: 2095359404400, Handlers: [<QueueHandler (NOTSET)>]  # The same logger
Logger: 1934246029680, Handlers: []
Logger: 1698863065456, Handlers: []
```

Comment: If I try, I get only one and the same logger. I'm rather surprised that you get different loggers.

Comment: I'd be a little careful trying to derive any meaning out of the `id` function. When you're using "fork" for processes in particular, the memory space is copied to the child using a "copy on write" mechanism, so memory addresses may be the same between parent and children, but as soon as the child modifies a given memory location it can get moved (Basically it won't copy the data to a new location until it changes). They may all start out the same, then once modified, they start to get moved to unique locations in memory. (`id` is implemented as the value of the pointer to the `PyObject` btw)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this behaviour too, using both `multiprocessing.Pool` and `concurrent.futures.process.ProcessPoolExecutor`. It works as expected (i.e. a single `QueueHandler` `handler` is added to the root logger for each process) if you create your processes via `multiprocessing.Process`, e.g. change your `main()` to:

```
q = Manager().Queue()

workers = []
for i in range(10):
    worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_queue_logger,
                                     args=(q,))
    workers.append(worker)
    worker.start()
for w in workers:
    w.join()
```

I presume the extra (and unwanted) handlers when using a `pool` are due to a logger instance that has already had a `QueueHandler` `handler` added being available to the `get_queue_logger` function in another process, but I don't understand how (edit - see EDIT#2 below). Incidentally, I see this issue when using a `pool` when `multiprocessing.set_start_method` is set to either 'spawn' or 'fork'.

It also means that the first code example in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes doesn't work as expected when using the approach mentioned here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor.

EDIT#1: note that this issue (different and sometimes duplicated ids for the root logger, and the `QueueHandler` `handler` sometimes getting added more than once per process) only seems to occur on MacOS (10.15.7). The same code on Ubuntu 19.10 results in the *same* id for every logger, and `QueueHandler` only gets added once per process.

EDIT#2: It turns out that the addition of more than one `QueueHandler` `handler` being added to the root logger per process when using a pool was caused by submitting more tasks to the pool than available cpus/threads. As noted in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) "Worker processes within a Pool typically live for the complete duration of the Pool’s work queue", and in the case of my Mac laptop (4 cpus) this results in some worker processes receiving more than one task, adding a new `QueueHandler` `handler` to the root logger each time. If you're using `multiprocesing.Pool` you can work around this issue using the `maxtasksperchild=1` argument, but this functionality doesn't appear to be available for `concurrent.futures.process.ProcessPoolExecutor`. The reason I saw differences re multiple `QueueHandler` handlers between macOS and Ubuntu (EDIT#1) is that my Ubuntu machine has 128 threads, and so each of the 10 calls to `get_queue_logger()` where being assigned to different processes. macOS still reports different (but no longer duplicated) ids for the loggers, due to it's default use of 'spawn' rather than 'fork'; if you set `multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')` together with `multiprocesing.Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)`, you then get the same logger ID in all cases.